# Всегда ли церковь при монастыре или возможен (можно ли сказать) монастырь при церкви?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, авторская-пунктуация

> Правда, крупный доминиканский монастырь при церкви
>   Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва, что находится ровно за углом от Пантеона
>   (как смешно бы это ни звучало), ну, на следующей площади, так вот,
>   этот монастырь, где раньше располагалась, кстати, инквизиция и где тот
>   зал, в котором обличили Джордано Бруно, Калиостро и других
>   отступников, вот почему-то его колокол почти каждый раз спешит и
>   начинает первый! За минуту! Оставим это на совести инквизиторов, тем
>   более что по этому знаку, словно по волшебству, площадь начинает
>   заполняться людьми.

Допустимы ли и все ли расставленные знаки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, **текст составлен некорректно (в его первой части неясна грамматическая основа)**.  Я могу прочитать его примерно так (хотя надо видеть контекст для окончательного решения):

Правда, крупный доминиканский монастырь при церкви Санта-Мария-сопра-Минерва, **находится** ровно за углом от Пантеона (как смешно бы это ни звучало) – ну, на следующей площади.

**Так вот,** колокол этого монастыря,  где раньше располагалась, кстати, инквизиция и где тот зал, в котором обличили Джордано Бруно, Калиостро и других отступников, – **вот** почему-то его колокол почти каждый раз спешит и начинает первый!

За минуту! Оставим это на совести инквизиторов, тем более что по этому знаку, словно по волшебству, площадь начинает заполняться людьми.

**А монастырь при церкви** – это вполне возможно, если он был построен позже, чем церковь.

...в 13-м веке доминиканский орден основал на базе церкви монастырь. https://www.votpusk.ru/country/dostoprim_info.asp?ID=17872

Другие примеры: В 1360 г. и была построена церковь Нерукотворного образа Спаса. Через некоторое время при церкви образовался монастырь, первым настоятелем которого стал Андроник. https://monastyri-mira.livejournal.com/75471.html